# Alice, Beatrice and a tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a tournament of $2^n$ players, Alice and Beatrice ask what's the probability that they'll not compete if they've the same level of play?

Let :

- $A_i$ : Alice plays the $i$-th tournament ;
- $B_i$ : Beatrice plays the $i$-th tournament ;
- $E_i$ : Alice and Beatrice don't compete at the $i$-th tournament.

---

For the moment, I was only able to calculate
$$P(A_i) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} \quad \forall^{\;i}_{\; 1 \dots n}$$

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Assuming every result is equally probable,

- How many contests are there? (All but one of the competitors need to be knocked out)
- How many potential pairings are there?
- What proportion of potential pairings actually meet in a contest? Can you simplify this?

Comment: I think there's $2^{n-1}$ contest. I suppose there's $\binom{2^n}{2}$ initial pairs possibles. But I doesn't understand your third point. Can you explain?

Comment: @hlapointe: There are $2^n-1$ contests, as all but one must be knocked out, not $2^{n-1}$.  As you say there are ${2^n \choose 2}$ initial pairs possible, but it might be helpful to write this as $\dfrac{2^n(2^n-1)}{2}= 2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$.   Divide the former by the latter and you get $\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ as the probability of Alice and Beatrice meeting.

Comment: Ok. But can you explain the logic behind your steps because I don't really understand why that works?!.

Comment: There are $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ possible pairs and they are equally probable so the probability one given contest is Alice v. Beatrice is $\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}$.  In fact there are $2^n-1$ contests and none of them are repeat pairings, so the probability any of them are    Alice v. Beatrice is $(2^n-1) \times \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

[ Note that A and B here do not necessarily stand for Alice and Beatrice ]

```
A -----
       |-------- A ------
B ------                |
                        |---- D ----------
C -----                 |                 |
       |-------- D ------                 |
D ------                                  |
                                          |------ D
E -----                                   |
       |-------- F ------                 |
F -----                |                  |
                       |---- F ----------
G -----                |
       |-------- G ----
H ----
```